# php.ini PATH section has no effect

Tags: php

I am using PHP-FPM with Apache and try to set custom php.ini settings inside a [PATH=...] directive. For example:

```
[PATH=/var/www/mysite]
memory_limit = 512M
```

I placed the file into `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-mysite.ini`

According to `phpinfo()` the file is being parsed and everything works if I leave out the [PATH]-part or use a [HOST=...] directive. Solely [PATH=...] is not being activated. Triple checked the path is correct.

My test file is saved in `/var/www/mysite/htdocs/php.php` so I also tried `[PATH=/var/www/mysite/htdocs]` in case this doesn't work recursivly but still it has no effect at all.

Any ideas on why [PATH=] doesn't seem to work at all?

Comment: I think you are looking in fact for the `include_path` config option. `include_path = /var/www/mysite`

Comment: No, I'm not trying to include files but to set php config values for specific php files being executed in specific directories. My goal is to have custom php.ini configs for every vhost.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache and php7.4-fpm